# Unit of circle radius in google maps javascript api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a circle with radius X kilometers, but it occurred to me that the radius option isn't being measured in km, since the api example has a radius of 400,000 but only actually goes out about 500 miles.

does anyone know what unit it's using?

Comment: You can answer your own question which flags it in the list as answered. Having done that, you can accept your own answer after a bit too.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The standard unit is meters. Use math to adjust.

Comment: Try to draw a circle with 6371000 meters and look what happens ;-)

The only way is do 6371000 * PI / 2...

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer has indicated, meters is the default unit. So if you're after km, just multiply by 1000 for meters on the radius property.

```js
// Add radius overlay to map
const set_radius = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: "#f38038",
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#f38038",
    fillOpacity: 0.25,
    map: your_map_variable,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    radius: 20 * 1000, // 20km
});
```